# Visual cue of when ClickLock has been activated?

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse, touchpad

I am using Windows's ClickLock feature for touchpads.  It lets me
create the effect of holding down the left mouse button and dragging
the pointer for long distances, either for selecting a lot of things
or moving a window a great distance.  If there is not enough space to
move my finger on the touchpad, I can lift my finger from the touchpad
without creating the effect of letting go of the mouse button.  I can
then place my finger down elsewhere on the touchpad and resume the
move.

This is especially important when I avoid the use of the left button
by double-tapping the touchpad to emulate a left button click.
The equivalent to click-and-hold is the double-tap and hold (keep
finger on the touchpad).  If ClickLock is enabled, I only have to
double-tap and hold for a fraction of a second before windows
considers the the left mouse
button to be locked down.  I can then use the touchpad to move
the pointer as much as I like, with multiple swipes if needed.
To release the mouse button, I just need to tap.

As far as I can see, this feature is only useful when tapping the
touchpad to emulate a left button click.  Oddly enough, and
thankfully, it *only* works when tapping the touchpad to emulate a
left button click, even though there is nothing in the Mouse
Properties panel to indicate that this is the only circumstance in
which the feature works.

The only additional behaviour needed to perfect this feature is a
visual indication of when you've held the left button down long enough
for Windows to consider the left button to be locked down.  As soon as
you see the indication, you can then proceed with moving the pointer.
As mentioned above, this essentially means a visual indication of when
you've "holded" enough in the double-tap-and-hold on the touchpad.

**Does Windows have a setting for a visual cue of when you've
tapped-and-holded the touchpad long enough for ClickLock to
activate?**

While I am on Windows 10, I'm really not sure if the question
and/or answer is specific to Windows 10.

Comment: Does your touchpad Click Lock show a different mouse cursor?  Common mice do this and then a long way down you can still see that Click Lock is active.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I looked through all my Lenovo TouchPad Synaptics setup and there is nothing that gives me my LogiTech mouse middle click, which is why I use my (real) Mouse

Comment: I've hived out the middle mouse button functionality as a separate issue.  I'm just interested in the posted question simply to enable use of the touchpad for left mouse button functionality -- because I find it more convenient.  It may be due to decades of having done that.

Comment: I checked those settings as well and do not see the Click Lock you want - just Click and Drag.

Comment: It's not a Synaptics feature, it's a general Windows feature. Unfortunately, my new overpriced and mediocre laptop has no Synaptics. I was reading the info for the wrong version of the laptop model, and based on that, I shelled out for it. [Here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/106624-turn-off-mouse-clicklock-windows.html) is a webpage on how to access Windows ClickLock.

Comment: That feature does not work reliably for me.  I saw a similar article, tried it and turned it off. For a whole variety of reasons, I still prefer a mouse for this work

Comment: I have to agree that sometimes, when I think the button is locked, it isn't.  That's why I want a visual cue.\

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question/desire as you. I went searching, landed here.

Could not find anything, so I decided to write my own script to achieve exactly this.

https://github.com/mmikeww/ClickLock-Indicator

Enjoy

Comment: Thanks so much!  Unfortunately, I need something that responds this way on computers that are locked down (severely limited user rights) and not.  So I was hoping that the solution would be native to Windows.  I hope that your solution helps others!